# EntityType ' ' has no key defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So I have been following this tutorial on ASP.NET. I have created a Model and intend on generating a Controller with views, using Entity Framework. However I have been stuck on this error for nearly hours researching causes and its only 2 lines of code and I can't for the life of me understand how I am getting this error.

Link to Tutorial https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/introduction-to-asp-net-mvc-8322?l=Omf358Zy_1604984382 
[image: This is all the code I have written]
[image: Receiving this message]

Comment: Add [Key] attribute to your primary key.

Comment: I have attempted the option of adding the [Key] above "TaskID" however I don't have a database linked yet it does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go:

You should to add the [KEY] attribute for your TaskID like this code:

```
public class Tasks
{
 [Key]
 public int TaskID {get;set;}
 public string taskStatus {get;set;}
}
```

Hope it helps;)

Comment: Ah, the reason it didn't work first time was because I didn't post the namespace. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

**Using the `[Key]` Attribute**

Consider setting a [`[Key]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.keyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute on the primary key for this class :

```
[Key]
public int TaskID { get; set; }
```

This data attribute will let Entity Framework know how to properly recognize this as an identifier for this entity when performing queries, updates, etc.

**Using Built-In Conventions**

Entity Framework can usually automatically identify it your field as referenced in [this Code First Conventions article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/efdesign/2010/06/01/conventions-for-code-first/) :

> Previously Code First would infer that a property is a primary key if
>   the property is called `Id` or `<class name>Id`.
>
> The only change to
>   this convention is that once primary key properties are detected if
>   their type is ‘int’, ‘long’ or ‘short’, they are registered as
>   identity columns in the database by default. Primary key detection is
>   not case sensitive.

Comment: It's not case sensitive: it says so right in the quote you posted. It just can't find it because the class name is pluralized.

Answer (score 1):

Entity framework expects a primary key, you can add it by

```
[Key]
public int TaskID { get; set; }
```

Or try renaming it

```
public int TasksID { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In EntityFramework, when you try to set a primary key, you can work with dataannotations or conventions. If you use conventions it needs to be `<className>Id` or just `Id`. Else you need to specify `[Key]` above the property.

Answer (score 0):

`[Key]` should work, remember to rebuild your project. If you've already got migrations for creating the schema then you will have to either change them, or add a new one.

I would recommend changing your class name to `Task` instead of `Tasks`. Your class looks like a singular item, not a list of items. This should help in a couple of ways:

1. EF will properly pick up the ID of `TaskID` (it looks for field that is either labelled only ID, or `<classname>ID` if I remember correctly). You won't have to force it with the `[Key]` annotation.
2. Your DbSet can now be called `Tasks`, which should be more correct: a set of `Task`s, instead of being a set called `Tasks` which holds several individual `Tasks` items. I think C# can tell the difference, but can you, without inspecting each reference?